# getRowIndexRelativeToVisibleRows is return "undefined" after sorting column in Datagrid of mui-x

Tags: mui-x-data-grid

having problem to show sorted row's index as order.

set renderCell as like this and used getRowIndexRelativeToVisibleRows function instead of getRowIndex since it deprecated since version up.

```
renderCell: (r) => {
            const t = r.api.getRowIndexRelativeToVisibleRows(r.id);
            return t + 1;
        },
```

this is DataGrid component props

```
<DataGrid
                        initialState={{
                            pagination: {
                                paginationModel: {
                                    pageSize: 25,
                                },
                            },
                        }}
                        rowCount={syncByPeriod?.data?.list?.length || 0}
                        pageSizeOptions={[10, 25, 50]}
                        autoHeight
                        loading={syncByPeriod?.isMutating}
                        rowSelection={false}
                        rows={syncByPeriod?.data?.list || []}
                        columns={[...basicColumns, ...AppIdColumns, ...extraColumns]}
                        disableRowSelectionOnClick
                    />
```

then it works fine in the first place but "getRowIndexRelativeToVisibleRows" will return undefined for all rows if you sort any of column.

attach video to make understand easier .

how can I fix this? ("순위" is Order)

[image]